# How to check which "/dev/pty/x" file my putty session is using?

Tags: terminal, tty, putty

I opened quite a few putty sessions to my remote Ubuntu machine.

For each of the session, I got a `/dev/pts/x` file assigned to it. Like below:

```
crw--w---- 1 xxx tty  136, 0 Feb   5 23:08 0
crw--w---- 1 xxx tty  136, 1 Feb   5 23:23 1
crw--w---- 1 xxx tty  136, 2 Feb   5 16:10 2
crw--w---- 1 xxx tty  136, 3 Feb   5 23:20 3
crw--w---- 1 xxx tty  136, 4 Feb   5 23:21 4
crw--w---- 1 xxx tty  136, 5 Feb   5 23:21 5
crw--w---- 1 xxx tty  136, 6 Feb   5 23:25 6
c--------- 1 root root   5, 2 Feb   4 10:28 ptmx
```

So how can I tell which putty session is using which pts file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tty` command will provide the device associated with the current session:

```
tty
/dev/pts/1
```

If there is no current terminal device, `tty` will report an error and exit with a non-zero status value

```
tty
not a tty
```

This allows you to write code that acts differently depending on whether or not it's attached to a terminal:

```
if tty >/dev/null
then
    # This is attached to a terminal device
    :
else
    # This is not
    :
fi
```

Comment: Ah... thanks! `tty` command does the trick. I am new to Linux so I am not aware of this command yet. `who` command cannot because it lists all the same login name. Thanks!

Comment: why not use `tty -s` (or `--silent` , `--quiet` ) instead of redirecting to `/dev/null` doesn't all tty suport it ?

Comment: @Archemar I wanted to give a POSIX solution, and the [POSIX version of `tty`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tty.html) takes no options

Comment: `tty` reports the terminal device open on its stdin. That's not the same as checking whether your process belong to a session attached to a terminal (though in practice would be good enough in most cases). `ps -o tty= -p "$$"` would report the sessions' tty if any (or `?` otherwise)